# Why does '||' operator return '[ ]'?

Tags: ruby

I tested this on console:

```
[] || 1 # => []
```

Shouldn't it return the value that exits, and not `[]`? I can change it to ternary operator, which works fine, but why does the condition above not work?

Comment: What is a value that exits? Do you mean the return value?

Comment: Question is not clear. Why would it not return `[]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `[]` is truthy value in Ruby, so the second part of your expression is never executed, it always evaluates to `[]`. In Ruby, just `false` and `nil` aren't truthy.

Oh, anyway, you don't need that. `map` returns an empty array if the array is empty.

```
Model.new(
  name: abc.name,
  description: abc.description,
  product_ids: abc.product_ids.map(&:id) 
)
```

Comment: My pleasure Sir ;)

Comment: @Ursus actually it should be just `abc.product_ids` - it will contain actual ids, so attempt to map would cause error. Assuming, of course, that it's a method generated by `has_many :products` association.

Comment: Yeah, that too.

Answer (score 3):

The exact semantics of `||` are:

1. if first expression is not `nil` or `false`, return it
2. if first expression is `nil` or `false`, return the second expression

So since `[]` is truthy it will evaluate to `[]`, as explained by @Ursus.